# how to display search box in UITable view when user scroll in UPWard direction after scrolling in downward direction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uisearchcontroller

I want to display search box at the top of view when user scroll in upward direction(-y axis) after user scroll in some downward direction(+y axis). I am new to IOS so i don't now how to do it.
Please answer using objective c language.

Comment: you can track scrolling by implementing  `UIScrollViewDelegate`

Comment: @LalKrishna yes i am doing by using these method *scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView* but i didn't how to display search bar when certain condition fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

use this code I hope it would help you

class TableViewController : UITableViewController {

var searchBar:UISearchBar?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 44, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
    view.addSubview(searchBar!)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    //navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.title = "nbbnbb"
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 88), animated: true)

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 30
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "hello"

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: thanks but as i am working with objective c language so i need answer  in objective c .